# How do I change the background color of my settings flyout in windows store app?

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I am using HTML5/JS to build my app and the CSS is not applying for some reason. I am still seeing the default color. Can I not override it when you press windows+I?

Here is the CSS for reference:

```
.win-settingsflyout {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't, you'll always get the color of your Start Screen

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a class to apply the color.

```
<style>
.colors{background-color: lightblue;}
</style>
```

then add this class to your div tag. `<div class='win-content colors'></div>`

Hope it'll work!

Answer (score 1):

Here in my sample app for the 'about' flyout. Is the background is red.

```
<div class="win-content" style="background: red;">
```

The full code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About</title>
        <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">WinJS.UI.processAll();</script>
        <script src="/js/about.js"></script>
        <link href="/css/about.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- BEGINSETTINGSFLYOUT -->
        <div class="apback" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" aria-label="App Settings Flyout" data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'about',width:'narrow'}">
            <!-- Use either 'win-ui-light' or 'win-ui-dark' depending on the contrast between the header title and background color -->
            <div class="win-ui-dark win-header" style="background-color: #333333"> <!-- Background color reflects app's personality -->
                <button type="button" onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.show()" class="win-backbutton"></button>
                <div class="win-label"><span data-win-res="{textContent: 'info'}"></span></div>
                <img src="../images/smalllogo.png" style="position: absolute; right: 40px;"/>
            </div>
        <div class="win-content" style="background: red;">
                <div class="win-settings-section">
                    <label>Test App</label>
                    <label>users</label>           

                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ENDSETTINGSFLYOUT -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "push" the change of you settings flyout background color with this CSS code:

```
.win-settingsflyout {
    background-color: #fff !important; background: #fff !important;
}
```